# How to handle refunds / returning goods with drupal commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

i'm just trying to figure out whatcould be the bestway to handle "refunds" and the return of the shipped goods with Drupal Commerce.
Is there some custom modules for that?How would you handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

There hasn't been created any module that handles this. How to approach this also depends a lot on the custom logic in your store like

- How are payments created
- How should payments be refunded
- What happens if returned goods has damage
- ...

Anyways, what you could do for starters, is to create a custom order status to mark that the goods have been returned. Most of the rest is most likely custom store logic anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/9199/full-or-partial-creditrefundreturn. [Commerce RMA](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rma) is mentioned to handle this then.

Answer (score 0):

great that the free RMA module in https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rma offers us the function. However, it may cause some fatal issues.